# How to use the ternary operator to increment a value

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

I was hoping someone can point out where I am going wrong? I haven't had much experience with using the Ternary operator but feel that there is good reason to use it here as it reduces code length.

However, I am getting the above error. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
Colour.R <= 255 ? Colour.R+=10 : Colour.R+=11;
```

The compiler returns

```
Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement
```

Where Colour represents a Color vector.

Answer (score 7):

The compiler is telling you exactly what's wrong - you can't use a conditional expression as a statement on its own. It's just an expression.

Fortunately in this case, you don't need to. You can write:

```
Colour.R += Colour.R <= 255 ? 10 : 11;
```

That has the benefit of being clearer, too :)

(I suspect your numbers are incorrect here, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: Thank you. That does make sense and look much clearer. And yes, the numbers are not correct. They were just typed quickly for the purpose of the question.